# What is the meaning of '-*' as case parameter in a fish shell script?

Tags: shell, fish

The official documentation of fish shell has [this example](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#function).

```
function mkdir -d "Create a directory and set CWD"
    command mkdir $argv
    if test $status = 0
        switch $argv[(count $argv)]
            case '-*'

            case '*'
                cd $argv[(count $argv)]
                return
        end
    end
end
```

I understand `case '*'` is like `default:` in C++ switch statement.

What is the meaning or usage of `case '-*'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a glob match.

`case '-*'` will be executed whenever the switched parameter starts with a "-".

And because only the first matching case will be used, `case '*'` as the last case is like "default:". If you had it earlier, it would swallow all cases after it.

Also the quotes here are necessary because otherwise fish would expand that glob, which would mean `case -*` would have all matching filenames in the current directory as parameters, so it would be true if the switched parameter is the name of a file in the current directory that starts with "-".

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [@faho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39557711/177116), I understand the purpose of `-*`.

`-*` is glob pattern. It is not at all different from patterns like `*.pdf` or `Report_2016_*`.

Author added this check to ignore all directories that start with `-`. It will create a directory that starts with `-` but will not set CWD to it.

The reason, `-` has special usage in shells.

For example, `cd -` does not change directory into a directory named `-`. Instead it switches to the last directory you were in.

Directories or files whose name start with `-` are a source of trouble. Following question on SO sister sites give an idea.

1. [How do you enter a directory that's name is only a minus?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53017/how-do-you-enter-a-directory-thats-name-is-only-a-minus)
2. [How do I delete a file whose name begins with “-” (hyphen a.k.a. dash or minus)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1519/2045)
3. [How to cd into a directory with this name “-2” (starting with the hyphen)?](https://serverfault.com/q/462739/89869)

No wonder author decided to ignore directory that start with `-`.